What is this 9-in-line latching connector?
1mm pitch. PCB side has U shaped pins that contact the top and bottom of the wire side connector - like an edge connector.




look for a manufacturer's logo

my Identiconn utility identifies it as a JST NSH.

PCB header: SM08B-NSHSS-TB
Plug housing NSHR-08V-S


{Source: Digikey}

It looks very similar to JST's "GH" series of connectors

Failing that, I'd recommend taking a couple of measurements and browsing Digikey's "rectangular connector" section (they've got very good filtering and photography). Keep an eye out for Molex as well, I remember someone else had something very close to the JST GH connectors, I can't quite remember who, but I think it was Molex.
EDIT: The more I look at it, the more those little outriggers on either side are bugging me, it is likely to be from JST as they have several connectors in that style, also check out the "NSH" and "ZE" series (they've probably got others too - check closely on the decals and bits of trim)

+1 Pin form factor is likely correct. Mechanical keying (outside the pin area) looks different, which is likely proprietary.

Spot on answer. It matches the JST NSH.
Thanks! You guys are awesome.

Pete, this isn't a forum and you can't post a thank you in the Your Answer box
(which should be kind of obvious). Please delete this post and "Accept" the best answer and give upvotes to any that are useful. Thanks.
